# Using exiftool to append text to a filename after it's completed

Tags: linux, exiftool

I have long used wonderful exiftool to strip out exif data from images.  Up to now, I've always done that in the same directory.  Now I'd like to make it place the exif-stripped file in a different directory, and add a "my-original-file-name-NO-EXIF.jpg" in there.  (The key thing is I want NO-EXIF to be AFTER the original file, but before the .jpg).

I have gotten it to place an identically named exif-stripped version by using this:

```
exiftool -o /home/dir/noexifdir/ -all= somefile.jpg
```

Is there any easy way to do this?  I have been scouring the example sites but they're all about how to use it to completely change the filename based on date, time, etc.

All I want is the equivalent of somefile.jpg to become somefile-NO-EXIF.jpg (on that output directory).  Not an identically named file as the original.

It seems like it should be easy...but clearly I'm needing help.  Anyone out there know what the correct command would be?

(Also, I need this to be within the actual "exiftool" command.  Not part of a bigger script!)

Edit:
One wrinkle is that I am using this in a drag-n-drop launcher on my desktop.  So I am not specifying the file directly, I am using the $1 variable which allows the command to be done on the file that's dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Example #9](https://exiftool.org/filename.html#ex9) on the exiftool's **Writing "FileName" and "Directory" tags** page.

`exiftool -overwrite_original -Filename=/home/dir/noexifdir/%f-NO-EXIF.%e -all= somefile.jpg`

Or, as mentioned in the third paragraph in the docs on the [`-o` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#o-OUTFILE-or-FMT--out)

`exiftool -overwrite_original -o /home/dir/noexifdir/%f-NO-EXIF.%e -all= somefile.jpg`

Comment: I don't think this is what I'm trying to do, but I think you gave me a big clue towards it.  I searched for the variables %f and %e and couldn't find them...but that's a big help.  I don't think I need to overwrite the original (and don't want to!).  More in a bit!

Comment: (And sorry, I see now that the way I wrote it makes it sound like I DO want to overwrite the original file, but what I meant was that I want the "somefile.jpg" that gets placed in the -o location to have "no-exif" in it.

Comment: I tried that -o /home/dir/noexifdir/%f-NO-EXIF.%e line and unfortunately got a file named "-NO-EXIF" in that "noexifdir" directory.  I need it to include the original filename so that I can refer back easily to the original if I need to.

Comment: To clarify, I edited the original post, too.  Again, thank you for your help!!

Comment: So it turns out that these variables don't work with the drag-and-drop.  But when I type it on a regular command line, it's perfect, just like you suggested.  And when I put it into a script and ran the SCRIPT from the launcher on the desktop, it was fine too.  Worked perfectly.  So thank you!!  Nice to have this doing what I want it to!  :-)

Comment: You can find details on the % variables under the [`-w` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#w-EXT-or-FMT--textOut)

Comment: You might also check the docs on your drag&drop laucher to see if there's a way to escape percent signs.  For example, in a Windows bat file, you need to double the percent signs.

Comment: I saw that the percents need to double, but I'm on Linux.  I suspect it is something to do with the issue of the $1 not carrying over into the shell script correctly.  But to be honest, I have no clue and since you tipped me onto something else that got the job done that's enough for me!  Again, thank you!  Much appreciated!